# Object.wait waits forever

Tags: java

I have a problem using [`Object.notifyAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll--) and [`Object.wait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--).

The `Object.wait()` function keeps waiting, even though the other thread already called `Object.notifyAll()`.

I've tried a `try`/`catch`, using `Object.notify()` instead of `Object.notifyAll()`, debug output (showed that it notified, but just waits infinitely) and setting a timeout for `Object.wait()`. None of these fixed my problem.

```
    public String run(){
        //Creating the request
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(this.BaseUrl).build();
        //Enqueuing the request
        this.client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                Response = response.body().string();
                System.out.println(Response);
                synchronized (Response){//We have to do this synchronized
                    Response.notify();//Notifying here
                }
            }
        });

        try{
            //We'll wait until the Response got notified by the callbacks and then return it.
            synchronized (Response){//We have to do this synchronized
                Response.wait();
                return Response;
            }
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(Response);
        }
        return  null;
    }
```

The error I get is... Well... It just waits forever.

EDIT: I tried making a simple Web request class using OkHttp3 (not relevant.)
This is a full function, should be pretty reproducable.
It's exactly the same... It waits forever.

Comment: Is `this` the same instance for both threads? Are you sure it's already waiting *before* you notify?

Comment: Catching an `Exception` is rarely what you want to do, catching and *ignoring* an exception is almost never the right thing to do, especially when your code doesn't work.

Comment: `wait` and `notify` are *hard* methods to use. Really, really, chop-your-hand-off-if-you-hold-them-in-the-wrong-way hard. Unless you're doing an exercise to teach you about how hard and unpleasant they are to use, don't: use higher-level concurrency libraries.

Comment: @thatotherguy ,It's the same Instance, and the 'nice' output appears in the console long before the 'Notified' one appears.

Comment: @EmeldemelTV I copy-pasted your code into a file, started the second snippet, slept 1000ms, started the first one, and it works as expected. Can you please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: how you know it is (still) running? hard to believe that `wait` with timeout does not end after the given time...and how you expect to get an error with `catch (Exception ignored) { }`???

Comment: Iv'e made a reproducable example with exactly the same error.

Comment: `Response = response.body().string();` now you lock on an other object.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell exactly what you are doing and what the order of events are.  The following demonstrates what I believe you are trying to do.

```
    public class WaitDemo {
       Object lock = new Object();

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          new WaitDemo().start();
       }
       public void start() {
          new Thread(() ->
          {
             synchronized (lock) {
                try {
                   System.out.println("Waiting...");
                   lock.wait();
                   System.out.println("received notification");
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                   ie.printStackTrace();
                }
             }
          }).start();

          try {
             // give thread time to start
             Thread.sleep(3000);
          }
          catch (InterruptedException ie) {
          }
          synchronized (lock) {
             System.out.println("starting");
             lock.notifyAll();
             System.out.println("notified other thread");
          }

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From question:

> The `Object.wait()` function keeps waiting, even though the other thread **already called** `Object.notifyAll()`.

Javadoc of [`notifyAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll--) says:

> Wakes up all threads that are waiting on this object's monitor. A thread waits on an object's monitor by calling one of the [`wait`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) methods.

Only threads **current waiting** are woken up. No flag is set or anything, so threads that start waiting *after* the call to `notifyAll` will not see the call, and will have to wait until the *next* call to `notifyAll`.